# Find parent and child from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In the array below, some of the items are parent and some of them are its children.

I want to find parents(with depth 0) and their childrens(nested with depth 1 -- depth2 --- depth 3) and then push to another array.

So far what I did only works for depth 0 and depth 1, don't know what to do with more depths.

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/s3x5f4ap/2/

```js
const comments = [
  { "depth": 0,"id": "f35vz2f"},
  { "depth": 0,"id": "f359354"},
  {   "depth": 1,"id": "f35e0b0", "parent_id": "f359354" },
  {     "depth": 2, "id": "f35ji24", "parent_id": "f35e0b0"},
  {     "depth": 2, "id": "f35rnwb", "parent_id": ""},
  {     "depth": 2, "id": "f35ojh4", "parent_id": "f35e0b0" },
  {       "depth": 3, "id": "f35lmch", "parent_id": "f35ji24"},
  {       "depth": 3, "id": "f35kl96", "parent_id": "f35ji24"}]

const parent = comments.filter(cm => cm.depth == 0);
final = [];
final = parent;

comments.forEach(a => {
  final.forEach(c => {
    if (c.id == a.parent_id) {
      c.child = []
      c.child.push(a);
    }
  })
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: do you have a result for the given data?

Comment: not yet, i just logged the result in the jsfiddle i shared if i understand you correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all relations of the nodes and build a tree.

```js
var data = [{ depth: 0, id: "f35vz2f" }, { depth: 0, id: "f359354" }, { depth: 1, id: "f35e0b0", parent_id: "f359354" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35ji24", parent_id: "f35e0b0" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35rnwb", parent_id: "" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35ojh4", parent_id: "f35e0b0" }, { depth: 3, id: "f35lmch", parent_id: "f35ji24" }, { depth: 3, id: "f35kl96", parent_id: "f35ji24" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.parent_id] = t[o.parent_id] || {};
            t[o.parent_id].children = t[o.parent_id].children || [];
            t[o.parent_id].children.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i don't understand your code :) , that would be great if you could explain it

Comment: it jus takes for each node the relatiuon with the paren adn to the children. you could return just `t`. there you see each `id` and their children. as result, you get all nodes without any `parent_id`.

Comment: What happened to the orphan f35rnwb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to end up with a tree-like structure, I would do something like:

```js
var data = [{ depth: 0, id: "f35vz2f" }, { depth: 0, id: "f359354" }, { depth: 1, id: "f35e0b0", parent_id: "f359354" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35ji24", parent_id: "f35e0b0" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35rnwb", parent_id: "" }, { depth: 2, id: "f35ojh4", parent_id: "f35e0b0" }, { depth: 3, id: "f35lmch", parent_id: "f35ji24" }, { depth: 3, id: "f35kl96", parent_id: "f35ji24" }];
var attach_children_to_item = function (item, data) {
    item.children = data.filter(x => x.parent_id == item.id)
                        .map(x => attach_children_to_item(x, data));
    return item;
};
var tree = data.filter(x => x.depth == 0)
               .map(x => attach_children_to_item(x, data));
console.log(tree);
```

Note that you will have missing items if the `depth` > 0 and the `parent_id` does not correspond to another item.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for tree structure

Comment: Thanks! `map()` and `filter()`, my new best friends.

Comment: What happened to the orphan f35rnwb

Comment: It's an error. An item cannot be depth > 0 and have no parent. The same happens to items with a non-existing parent_id. It's easy to add a check and throw an error if needed.